# Need adventure map help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on an adventure map. I have characters that when you click on a sign that says: `(Character name here) Click to talk.` I used this command:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {
    BlockEntityTag: {
        Text1: "{\"text\":\"Wounded Man\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"say Wounded man: Who are you? Doesn't matter. There's a storm coming I suggest You find Shelter.\"}}",
        Text2: "{\"text\":\"Click to talk\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"say New Quest: Find Shelter\"}}",
        Text3: "{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"particle fireworksSpark\"}}"
    },
    display: {
        Name: "Custom Sign"
    }
}
```

I wanted it to say: `(@) Wounded Man: A storm's coming I suggest you find shelter...`, but instead it says: `(LordSockingham) Wounded man: A storm's coming and I suggest you find shelter...`. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this might be a result of the fact that it's the player that is performing the `/say` command. There might be some magic you could work with a `/tellraw`, but I'm not certain

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the player is the one who is running the command with JSON commands. One possible workaround is the `/trigger` command:

Before anything else, once:

```
/scoreboard objectives add TalkToWoundedGuy trigger
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"O"}
```

On a repeatingCommandBlock/chainCommandBlock loop, in order:

```
/scoreboard players enable @a TalkToWoundedGuy
/execute @p[score_TalkToWoundedGuy_min=1] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[name=O] ~ ~ ~ [all the 'say' commands you want, on different command blocks]
/execute @p[score_TalkToWoundedGuy_min=1] ~ ~ ~ [all the other commands you want, on different command blocks]
/scoreboard players set @a TalkToWoundedGuy 0
```

On the sign:

```
{Text1:"{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/trigger TalkToWoundedGuy set 1\"}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`/tellraw`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#tellraw) command instead of `/say` for greater control of content.

For example, you would cause the player to run the following command:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"[Wounded Man]: A storm's coming I suggest you find shelter..."}
```

Output:

> [Wounded Man]: A storm's coming I suggest you find shelter...

You `/give` command would instead become:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag: {Text1: "{\"text\":\"Wounded Man\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tellraw @a {\\\"text\\\":\\\"[Wounded Man]: A storm's coming I suggest you find shelter...\\\"}\"}}",Text2: "{\"text\":\"Click to talk\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"say New Quest: Find Shelter\"}}",Text3: "{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"particle fireworksSpark\"}}"},display: {Name: "Custom Sign"}}
```

Answer (score -2):

Tellraw runs from the console I believe. That should work if you're able to implement it into your script.